# How to render template inside of template with angular and django

Tags: python, angularjs, django

Question I want to be able to add a multiple Dimensions(Dimension Class) to my Sheet Class. What I would like to do is pass it into angular then back to Django if possible I just need help/guidance on how to do this I have looked a countless blogs and still can't come up with correct way of doing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Here is my sheet model and dimension model (model.py)

```
class Sheet(models.Model): 
    drawing_number = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    drawing_revision = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    heat_number = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    valc = models.CharField(max_length=255) 

class Dimension(models.Model): 
   description = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
   style = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
   target = models.IntegerField() 
   upper_limit = models.IntegerField() 
   lower_limit = models.IntegerField()
```

## Here is my view.py with sheet_from_create method and my test method for adding a dim that isn't working.

```
def sheet_form_create(request): 

        if request.method == 'GET': 
          sheet_form = SheetForm() 

        else: 
          sheet_form = SheetForm(request.POST) 
          cust_int = Customer.objects.latest('id').id 
          cust_int_plus = int(cust_int) + 1 
          c_date = datetime.now() 
          u_date = datetime.now() 


          if sheet_form.is_valid(): 
            drawing_number = sheet_form.cleaned_data['drawing_number'] 
            drawing_revision = sheet_form.cleaned_data['drawing_revision'] 
            heat_number = sheet_form.cleaned_data['heat_number'] 
            note = sheet_form.cleaned_data['note'] 
            valc = sheet_form.cleaned_data['valc'] 

            try: 
              get_cust = Customer.objects.filter(customer_name=customer_name).exists() 
            except: 
              get_cust = False 
            if get_cust == True: 
               c = Customer.objects.get(customer_name=customer_name) 
               c_id = c.customer_id 
            else: 
               creat_cust = Customer.objects.create(id=cust_int_plus, customer_id=cust_int_plus, customer_name=customer_name) 
               c_minus = cust_int_plus 
               c = Customer.objects.get(id=c_minus) 
               c_id = c.customer_id 

            sheet = Sheet.objects.create( 

              drawing_number=drawing_number, 
              drawing_revision=drawing_revision, 
              heat_number=heat_number, 
              note=note, 
              valc=valc, 
              customer_id=c_id) 
            return render(request, 'app/sheet.html') 
        return render(request, 'app/sheet_form_create.html', { 
          'sheet_form': sheet_form, 
          'title':'New Sheet', 

        })
```

## I tried this with ajax no luck It will not render my dim.html

```
        def add_dimensions(request): 
            data = {} 
            if request.method == 'POST': 
              dim_form = DimForm(request.POST) 
              if dim_form.is_valid(): 
                dim = Dimension() 
                description = dim_form.cleaned_data.get['description'] 
                style = dim_form.cleaned_data.get['style'] 
                target = dim_form.cleaned_data.get['target'] 
                upper_limit = dim_form.cleaned_data.get['upper_limit'] 
                lower_limit = dim_form.cleaned_data.get['lower_limit'] 

                dim.save() 
                data['description'] = dim.description; 
                data['style'] = dim.style; 
                data['state'] = "ok"; 
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json") 
              else: 
                 data = 'fail' 
                 return render(request, 'app/sheet_form_create.html') 
            else: 
              dim_form = DimForm() 
              return render(request, 'app/dim.html', {'dim_form': dim_form})
```

## Here is my sheet_form_create.html this is where I want my dim.html to render inside of as well

```
 {% extends "app/layout.html" %} 
        {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
        {% block content %} 



        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 



        <div class="row" > 
          {% crispy sheet_form %} 
        </div> 

        <body ng-app="dim_app"> 
         <!-- render my dim.html here somehow --> 
          <div ng-controller="DimCtrl"> 
              <div class="data"> 
              </div> 
              <button ng-click="save()">Click</button> 
          </div> 

        </body> 
        {% endblock %}
```

## Here is my dim.html

```
        {% extends "app/layout.html" %} 
        {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
        {% block content %} 



        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 


        <div class="row" > 
          {% crispy dim_form %} 
        </div> 

        {% endblock %}
```

## Last but not least my angular code that I have so far for testing purposes here is where I am most confused

```
dim_app = angular.module('dim_app', []); 


dim_app.controller('DimCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.num = 0; 
    $scope.save = function () { 
        $(".data").html("click:" + $scope.num); 
        //some how load dim.html in here how ever many times its clicked example they click 5 times render dim.html five times and save each on as a child record of sheet 
        $scope.num += 1; 
    }; 

}]);
```

## This is an example of what I would like it to look like

[image: Example of what I would like to see]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

## Here is my angular code

dim_app = angular.module('dim_form', [])

```
  .controller('dim_ctrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) { 

      $scope.show_dim = function () { 
          var comp = $compile("<div </div>")($scope); 
          $("#id").append(comp); 
      }; 
  }]) 
  .directive('myDim', function () { 
      return { 
          templateUrl: '/sheet/sheet_form_create.html/_dim' 

      }; 
  });
```

## Here is my sheet_form_create.html

```
    {% extends "app/layout.html" %} 
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
    {% block content %} 



    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 



    <div class="row" > 
      {% crispy sheet_form %} 
    </div> 

    <body ng-app="dim_form"> 
      <div ng-controller="dim_ctrl"> 
          <a href="#" ng-click="show_dim()">show</a> 
          <div id="d"></div> 
      </div> 
    </body> 

    {% endblock %}
```